# Is it possible to mock "command" when testing in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unit-testing, mocking, bats-core

One of my scripts is trying to figure out if all it's dependencies are installed when there is an error. In order to do that I use the built-in `command`. Let's assume the most limited version I could come up with (let's call that `script_to_test.sh`:

```sh
command -v pdfgrep
return $?
```

Now I have a [bats-core](https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) test file `test.sh`:

```sh
setup() {
  # See https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html
  load 'test_helper/bats-support/load'
  load 'test_helper/bats-assert/load'
  # See https://github.com/buildkite-plugins/bats-mock
  load 'test_helper/mocks/stub'
  DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$BATS_TEST_FILENAME" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
  PATH="$DIR/..:$PATH"
}

@test "Test mocking built-ins" {
  stub command \
    "-v pdfgrep : exit 17"
  run script_to_test.sh
  unstub command
  assert_failure 17
}
```

When I run that, I get:

```sh
`unstub command' failed
```

This is because the stubbed `command` was never called.
**Is it even possible to stub built-ins?**
**How can I test my scripts behavior where it depends on the environment?**

Comment: This question is about a very important thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, it is not possible, because built-in commands are part of the shell itself, and they cannot be easily replaced or stubbed! but maybe I can explain it to you with another approach using an example, in my scenario instead of relying on the built-in command directly, you can create a wrapper function or script that encapsulates the behavior of the built-in command and after that, you can stub or mock this wrapper function/script in your tests, for example when you run `test.sh` using Bats, it will execute the test case named `Test mocking built-ins`. so,I stubbed the `check_dependency` function to simulate the scenario where `pdfgrep` is not installed and the test expects the script to fail with an exit code of `1`!

you can move the check_dependency function into its own separate file, let's say `dependency_checker.sh`,and then source this file in both script_to_test.sh and test.sh so that they can access the function.

let me show you how:

dependency_checker.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_dependency() {
  command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
  return $?
}
```

script_to_test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

source dependency_checker.sh

check_dependency pdfgrep
return $?
```

test.sh:

```
setup() {
  load 'test_helper/bats-support/load'
  load 'test_helper/bats-assert/load'
  load 'test_helper/mocks/stub'
  DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$BATS_TEST_FILENAME" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
  PATH="$DIR/..:$PATH"
}

@test "Test mocking built-ins" {
  stub check_dependency \
    "pdfgrep : return 1"
  run script_to_test.sh
  unstub check_dependency
  assert_failure 1
}
```

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection - except for too many indircetions".

Comment: The solution only works if `check_dependency` is moved into it's own file outside of `script_to_test.sh`.  Change your answer and I'll mark it as solution. I assume any functions defined in a script will override whatever is set or mocked in the environment because scripting evaluates on the go. I don't like that property, but it's what we have. Guess I'll test the code separately and not inside the script.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to kind of achieve this:

1. Create mock versions of the commands that you want to mock as Bash scripts.
2. Update `PATH` when running the test so that the mock scripts are picked up instead of the real ones.

Doing this manually is probably too much hassle. [Shellmock](https://github.com/capitalone/bash_shell_mock) is apparently a framework that automates this.